# How to rewrite htaccess properly, adding parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i've tried to find an answer on my question, but i didn't found the exactly answer.

I have a site: `www.website.com`

Every page is loaded in this way: `www.website.com/index.php?page=page1`

Now i'm trying to implement pass parameters through URL like this:

```
www.website.com/index.php?page=page5&**id=17**
```

But i can't understand how. Very thank you in advice for you time.
Cheers

Comment: Do you need different id's? What part of the url dictates which id to use? Maybe you need something else.

Comment: Hi RST,
Template oblige me to have the following URL: `www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename`
My question is: How to append to this URL a parameter ?

Thank you in advice

Comment: you should be fine with the url of your example when you remove the **. It is not clear where you are generating this links.

Comment: The problem is that even if i go to the following link
`www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename?id=17`
i got redirected to 
`www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename`
and i think so it is a htaccess problem, am i wrong?

thank you RST

Comment: if your url is `www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename&id=17` (notice the & instead of ? ) where do you want it to go to?

Comment: Oops. I noticed my error. I wrote on link generator ? instead of &.
Thank you, you saved my work

Comment: So your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can access your pages as:

```
http://domain.com/page1
```

OR

```
http://domain.com/page1?id=17
```

Comment: Maybe i just wrote wrong my question.
Template oblige me to have the following URL:

'www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename'

My question is: How to append to this URL a parameter ?
Very thank you in advice Mr. anubhava

Comment: Sorry it is still unclear what rewrite rule is needed here. Where do you want to add a parameter to make it `www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename?id=17` ? Can you not use `www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename?id=17` in your HTML page?

Comment: The problem Sir is that even if i go to the following link
`www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename?id=17`
i got redirected to 
`www.website.com/index.php?page=pagename`
and i think so it is a htaccess problem, am i wrong?

thank you Sir

Comment: Well it could be but I can tell only after seeing your current htaccess which you haven't shown in the question.

Comment: I didn't show htaccess cause i can't find it in my host (italian host) and i think no one before me wrote the htaccess (i'm not the site's creator)